# Application_Start() vs ApplicationStart()

Tags: c#, asp.net, naming, naming-standards

Why is the method in Global.asax called `Application_Start()` and not `ApplicationStart()`?

According to [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions) method names should be in Pascal case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an event handler, in addition to being a method.
The convention for naming event handlers is `EventOrigin_EventName(...)`.  Event origin can be a name of an instance (camel case), or a name of a class (Pascal case), or some other meaningful name (Pascal case).  Event name is Pascal case.  Underscore between.  Visual Studio uses this naming convention when it creates default event names.

```
emergencyStopButton_PreviewKeyDown(...)
Form_BeforeOpen(...)
```

related: 
[Naming C# events and handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317109/naming-c-sharp-events-and-handlers-properly)